# rpm package management on system without inet access

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I have a CentOS 6.7 system that is behind a firewall with no outbound. It is a vanilla, working rig.

I need to install:
- jemalloc
- redis

I have the rpm for jemalloc on the system locally, but it won't install complaining about requiring glibc

```
[root@localhost tmp]# rpm -ivh jemalloc-3.6.0-8.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by jemalloc-3.6.0-8.el7.centos.x86_64
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

But that makes no sense to me, as glibc is in the local rpm repository, it appears to me:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# rpm -qa|grep glibc
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
[root@localhost tmp]# yum install glibc
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost tmp]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: jemalloc requires glibc 2.14 and you have version 2.12 installed.

Comment: @n8te Thanks, I see what you refer to. But for centos 6.7, there doesn't seem to be glibc 2.14

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6702) CentOS forum discussion. It's not a solution to your problem but worth reading as they strongly advise against trying to install glibc 2.14 on CentOS 6.

Comment: @n8te Thanks. I get it now. See answer I posted below. (I referred to a running centos 6.x system to see what versions of things were there)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Use jemalloc 3.6.0-1 on Centos 6.x, do not use (or try to use) jemalloc 3.6.0-8, as that is for Centos 7....

Comment: +1 Glad to see you found an alternative solution.